# How to pass updated values of a variable from one JS file to another?

Tags: javascript

Suppose, I have two JavaScript files Javascript1 and Javascript2

In Javascript1 I have a variable myAge initially set to 0 like `myAge = 0`. Below it I change it to 1 via some function.

Now even after declaring the variable as global and putting the Javascript1  above the Javascript2 in my HTML, I am not able to get the updated value of `myAge`. It always passes `0`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so that we can comment on your specific example.

Comment: Are you loading them into the same HTML page? Then they should share all the global variables.

Comment: @Barmar not necessarily in the same scope though -- it depends on how it's being loaded and what the constructs are.  This is why we need an example.

Comment: Is the code in the other file running after you call the function?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Unless modules are being used there's just one global scope.

Comment: There's also function scope, or you can create your own object scope ... too many ways scope can be used in JS.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer That's why I specifically said "share all the global variables". Of course if it's not a global variable then obviously they're not shared.

Comment: We don't know without an example if the variable is actually global.

Comment: Hey, yeah variable is global, no they are on diff. html pages. 
So the thing was I declared variable x. on javascrip1 and html1 (the main html linked to javascript1, all function on html1 are performed by javascript1). 
whey I did this?because there's a button on the html1, which when i click increase the value of x. lets say its initially 0 now when I clicked the button on html1 , it changed to 1.
Now on my html2 connected to javascript2, I want to show the difference of some number y with respect to x 
lets says y = 100 then difference = 100-1 should be there on html2, but x=0  is there

Comment: since its not getting updated to 1, difference is always 100-0 = 100